# C++ Multi threaded or multi processed server for event driven jobs

Tags: c++, multithreading, rest, server, multiprocessing

I've developed a large application in **C++** that **performs jobs**, such that it **receives input x and outputs y**. For this application, **speed is the top priority**. The application is **capable of running concurrently**. I want to modify this application to implement a HTTP server so that it can be used as **an REST API**, where users sends x and receives y as its response. The HTTP server will serve the requests by spawning a new thread to run the job, **or** a new process.

I have some concerns with multithreading:

Depending on the users input, **the job can hang indefinitely**. Therefore it is essential that some kind of **time out mechanism** is implemented which will terminate the job if a time limit is exceeded. If the job was to run as a separate process, this can easily be done by simply ending the process.

However if the job was ran on a thread, I would have to modify the actual application to **cooperate with the time out code** and also guarantee the program will be able to **recover all memory at any given time**, which would be a lot work (since the code base is large and optimised) and also may have implications for performance (e.g. continuously checking if the time limit has been exceeded).

I've heard that spawning processes is quite slow on **Windows**, so I had a idea to spawn n amount of worker processes when starting up the server and then just send the input information from the server to a free worker and send back the output. (Is this practise of pre-spawning processes a thing?)

When it comes to multi processing I'm concerned with **communications between the process** which will have to send output information to it's spawner once its completed. Additionally, I've heard that there's better performance with multi threading over multi processing (Windows).

I'm honestly a bit perplexed as to which route I should go down and was wondering if anyone had any advice or insight into how a server application that performs requests driven jobs should optimally work.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what options you are considering and what you perceive as issues or downsides of each. Multithreading + a mechanism to end threads/workers sounds reasonable depending on what server-side language you are using.

Comment: @Evert I've updated the question with your feedback in mind. The application uses C++. Are you suggesting that a worker should run on its own thread rather then its own process? If so, you got any reasons why?

Comment: There would have been a bunch of programming languages where I would have been able to give specific advice, but C++ is not one of those.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this problem requires a bit of knowledge about HOW "the job can hang indefinitely".

You will have to handle this logic somewhere, and if I were you, I would prefer to keep everything inside C++. Generally, I would consider it a code smell if somebody starts to put a lot of calls to the underlying system in their codebase. Those types of things often lead to security issues.

In addition, I would prefer to keep everything contained in C++ because it will make the code more portable to different OS's. If you start trying to manage the OS's processes, then all of a sudden, your codebase is tied to that specific OS (in this case, Windows). Now if you try to deploy that to the cloud, you need a Windows server.